# No route matches missing required keys: [:permalink]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i'm working on **rails 4.2.5**, **ruby 2.3.1p112**.

I'm facing this error missing required keys permalink.

Error message is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"product_categories", :requirements=>{:id=>/[^.?]/}} missing required keys: [:permalink]
```

My View (error at)

```
= link_to top_level.name, product_category_path,:permalink => top_level.permalink, :title => "Shop Designer Brands in #{top_level.name}", "data-tracking-event" => "PCInHeader", "data-label" => top_level.name, :class => "gaevent"
```

My routes

```
match "/catalog/*permalink" => "product_categories#show", :as => "product_category", :via => [:get], :requirements => { :id => /[^.?]/ }
```

Help out me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `permalink` hash as a parameter in url helper

```
= link_to top_level.name, product_category_path(permalink: top_level.permalink), title: "Shop Designer Brands in #{top_level.name}", "data-tracking-event" => "PCInHeader", "data-label" => top_level.name, :class => "gaevent"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do product_category_path(permalink: permalink) As first paramter is consider as Id but here you need permalink instead of ID